# Find length of longest binary subsequence with at most k ones

Tags: c++, algorithm

as can be seen in title, I need to find length of longest binary subsequence with at most `k` ones. For instance:

k = `3`, binary_seq = `11100001101011010000011`, answer is: 10 (because longest subsequence is 11100001101**0110100000**11)

k = `1`, binary_seq = `00101001001`, answer is: 5 (because longest subsequence is 00101**00100**1)

I did it but in quadratic time (I guess)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename V>
void pop_front(V & v)
{
    v.erase(v.begin());
}

int main() {
    int k,maxLength=0,lengthOfSequence;
    bool one;
    string bin_seq;
    lengthOfSequence = 1;
    vector<unsigned> myList;
    cin >> k;
    cin >> bin_seq;
    for(char num : bin_seq) {
        myList.push_back(0);
        if (num == '1') {
            for(int i = 0; i < lengthOfSequence;++i)
                ++myList[i];
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < lengthOfSequence;++i) {
            if(myList[i] <= k) {
                if (lengthOfSequence-i > maxLength) {
                    maxLength = lengthOfSequence-i;
                }
            }
        }
        lengthOfSequence++;
        while(myList[0]>k) {
            pop_front(myList);
            lengthOfSequence--;
        }

    }
    cout << maxLength << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

how to do it in smaller time complexity?

Comment: This is O(n) problem. One loop. Just do it. Don't create things like `myList`. Use iterators/indices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in O(n) with this algorithm:

- Make two indexes, one for the beginning and one for the end of the desired subsequence
- Keep expanding the sequence by increasing the `end` index until you reach the position of `k+1`-st `1`
- Before you continue expanding the sequence past `k+1`-st `1`, shrink the sequence by "pulling in" the start to skip over the earliest `1` in the sequence
- Each time you expand the sequence by increasing `end`, record the max length of the sequence
- Once you reach the end of the sequence, `max` will have the longest subsequence with at most `k` ones in it.

Comment: I understood everything except `k+1 -st 1` did you mean `k+1-startPosition==1` or something like that? I don't understand only this space between `-st` and `1`.

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz In your example of `"11100001101011010000011"` and `k==3`, zero-based position of `k+1`-st `1` (4-th `1`) is `7`. You expand the subsequence to `"1110000"`, then you reach 4-th `1`, so you must pull in the start index to get to `"1100001"`, then to `"10000110"`, and so on.

Comment: Oh I understand now. Now algorithm is easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Lets say the input is 1101011010000011

```
1101011010000011
fedcba9876543210  << Bit Positions
```

Now create an array containing indexes were bit are set. Maintain `i and j` as `j = (i + k-1)` while advancing both together by 1.

```
For K = 3
Array: 0 1 7 9 a c e f
i,j:   ^   ^
       max = 9 - (0-1) - 1

      -----------------------

       0 1 7 9 a c e f
i++,j++: ^   ^      
      max = (arr[j+1] - arr[i-1]) - 1
          = a - 0 - 1 = 9

      -----------------------

      0 1 7 9 a c e f
          ^   ^     
      max = (arr[j+1] - arr[i-1]) - 1
          =   c - 1 - 1 = 12- 1- 1 = 10 (as 10 > 9)

      -----------------------

      0 1 7 9 a c e f
            ^   ^       
      max = (e - 7) - 1 = 14 - 7 - 1 = 6. So max = 10

      -----------------------

      0 1 7 9 a c e f
              ^   ^     
      max = f-9 - 1 = 15-9-1 = 5 (<10).

      -----------------------

          0 1 7 9 a c e f
                    ^   ^       
      max = (f+1) - a - 1 = 16-10-1 = 5 (<10).


      So, max = 10;
```